# `Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` error while running `dotnet run` using a startup script

Tags: .net, linux, debian, startup, init

I'm trying to run a dotnet app using `dotnet run --configuration Release` at system server Startup/Reboot. I'm using a `init.d` script to acheive the same.

My startup script, located at `/etc/init.d/myscript` contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/user/myscripts/botScript.sh
```

Contents of `botScript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/bot/
nohup dotnet run --configuration Release &
```

When my server Starts or Reboots the startup script gets executed but `dotnet run` doesn't work. I get the following error(s):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Resolution.PackageDependencyProvider.ResolvePackagesPath(String rootDirectory, GlobalSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.get_NuGetCachePath()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.Exists()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.ShouldPrimeNugetCache()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel nugetCacheSentinel)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

But all other commands works fine in that script & even simply running `dotnet` works fine too (I have checked that). It's just that `dotnet run` doesn't work.

Yeah, but when I run the scripts, both `myscript` as well as `botScript.sh`, after loging in to my server, it works fine without any errors.

Please, can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I don't understand why it was downvoted

Comment: By the waym do you get warning "Warning: HOME environment variable not set. Disabling LTTng-UST per-user tracing." ?

Comment: @Artiom No, I just get the above error. I also tried to assign the `HOME` env. variable to `/home/user` still I get the same error(s).

Comment: So far there're two tickets to be related to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/354 and https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2385

Comment: Have you succeed to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Artiom No. Still looking for a solution. Need to get this done soon.

Comment: Could you write in your script current user name? May be script runs as root and it doesn't have home env, variable?

Comment: @Artiom I have tried to run as current user. Still same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's obviously a bug in `PackageDependencyResolver`, but to find a workaround, consider the order in which the `packages` folder is found:

1. global.json `{ "packages": "..." }`
2. `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable.
3. `{DefaultLocalRuntimeHomeDir}\packages`

Your code is falling all the way to case #3 above. To work around this, create an environment variable called `NUGET_PACKAGES` pointing to you packages folder. For example, in `botScript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/bot/
export NUGET_PACKAGES="/home/user/.nuget/packages" # <=== 
nohup dotnet run --configuration Release &
```

For more info, see [PackageDependencyResolver.cs](https://github.com/stuartleeks/dotnet-cli/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel/Resolution/PackageDependencyProvider.cs) and [PackageDependencyResolver.cs](https://github.com/borgdylan/dotnet-cli/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel/Resolution/PackageDependencyProvider.cs)

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't run dotnet with root user

If it runs from init.d, it is invoked with **root** user.
Running program with **root** will expose your machine to severe security issues, especially with .net core which is still under heavy development and so is **not** security hardened yet.

#### Run a service with specific user

Your error is probably cause by the fact that for `root` no packages directory is defined, however when you run it manually, it is with your `user` which has `/home/user/.nuget/packages` directory defined.

- From [asp.net core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction), you can setup a service and specify a user which will run dotnet
- Just use `su` command to run dotnet with the specified user

**Supervisor users**

Here an extract of supervisor conf for my own site

**`/etc/supervisor/conf.d/mysite.conf`**:

```
[program:mysite]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/mysite/MySite.dll
directory=/var/www/mysite
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/mysite.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/mysite.out.log
environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
user=www-data <=== SPECIFY A USER HERE
stopsignal=INT
```

#### Don't use `dotnet run` outside of development/debugging purpose

As `dotnet --help` says, the run command compiles and executes a project.

```
run           Compiles and immediately executes a .NET project
```

Compilation wil require additional steps, and then computing power and so additional time (each time it is run, even there is no changes in code). It wil also requires restore and build to work (which requires a normal developer user). It is also more failure prone because of the additional steps that could fail.

Instead run compilation once with your developer user and then run your program with a service user like www-data (which is kind of builtin user for websites)

```
dotnet MyCompiledAssembly.dll
```

Comment: I run supervisor in order to monitor the app. Should I run supervisor as a specific user in order to fix above mentioned exception?

Comment: @Artiom I have added the configuration I use

Comment: that's nice. Good answer. +100 from me.

Comment: www-data is present on machine, but /home/www-data is missing. What have I missed?

Comment: @Artiom www-data is a special user with home in /var/www but anyway why do you need to do a restore ? are you trying to recompile your program ?

Comment: @Artiom I have missed the run part of your command. I have updated my answer accordingly. If you really want to compile your project on startup then you need a user with all the setup environment for that like the user with which you developped the software :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130187/discussion-between-artiom-and-fab).

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried running the script by changing it to a unprivileged user. Still it didn't worked.
Btw, now I run the script using `rc.local` script.
And the answer by @diego works.

Comment: I have my configuration set the same as you with www-data as the user for the supervisor program but I am still getting this error. Does www-data need a home folder? Would love to get this working

Comment: @m.brookson Yes. www-data has /var/www as home on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Fab I cannot get this working with my .NET Core 2.0 application. I have the same configuration as this and have checked that the www-data user does have /var/www as it's home directory. I think my issue is slightly different to the one highlighted in this post. I created a GitHub issue here so any extra input would be greatly appreciated. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1037